# jQuery $.each ошибка

Tags: jquery

Ни один `console.log();` не отрабатывает, где ошибка?

```
$.each(json.data.period_list, function() {
                        var local_min = Math.min.apply(Math, this);
                        var local_max = Math.max.apply(Math, this);
                        min_data = min_data || local_min;
                        max_data = max_data || local_max;
                        console.log(0);
                        <? if($this->period_st_logic) { ?>
                            var local_value = '';
                            $.each(this, function() {
                                local_value += this + ',';
                            });
                            buffer += '<option value="' + local_value + '">'+ local_min + ' - ' + local_max +'</option>';
                            console.log(2);
                        <? }else{ ?>
                            min_data = (local_min < min_data) ? local_min : min_data;
                            max_data = (local_max > max_data) ? local_max : max_data;
                            console.log(3);
                        <? } ?>
                    });
```

Comment: смотрите в консоли на ошибки

Comment: пустая, нет ошибок

Comment: а сама функция запускается?

Comment: @Saidolim как это проверить?

Comment: @ИгорьВолков если `concole` не работает через `alert` проверьте

Comment: @Saidolim попробовал, ничего не происходит, выходит, что функция не запускается, не подскажите в чем может быть причина?

Comment: перед `$.each` сделайте `console.log(json.data.period_list)`. Если массив пустой, то ничего и не будет происходить